# Facebook iOS SDK list of permissions returning nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I have code in my Login controller that checks whether a user has granted certain permissions. The code was working fine for a few weeks, but until recently it stopped working as FBSession.activeSession().permissions is returning nil instead of a list of permissions

Anyone else have a similar problem or know what might be the cause?
I am using Parse + Facebook 
Here is my code (in Swift)

```
if FBSession.activeSession().state != FBSessionState.Open {

    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            if error != nil {
                println("User cancelled fb login")
            } else {
                println("Error with login: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            if user!.isNew {
                println("Brand new user signed up!")
            } else {
                println("Returning user logged in!")
            }
            self.voiceMeAPI.requestDataForUserMe { (finished) -> () in

                //This is printing nil
                println(FBSession.activeSession().permissions)

                if contains(FBSession.activeSession().permissions as [String], "user_friends") {
                    self.updateFriendsThenPushToHomeViewController(isNewUser: user!.isNew)
                } else {
                    dispatchOnMainQueueAfterDelay(0, { () -> () in
                        self.presentViewController(self.noFriendsListAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                }
            }

        }
    })
```

Comment: any luck? I have the same issue

Comment: Nothing :/ haven't been able to get a list of permissions

Answer (score 1):

Some of the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3) from the Facebook SDK page may have what you want. Specifically the section titled "Using Custom Login UIs."

Here is the Obj-C from the Facebook SDK Docs:

```
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    // Process error
  } else if (result.isCancelled) {
    // Handle cancellations
  } else {
    // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
    // should check if specific permissions missing
    if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
      // Do work
    }
  }
}];
```

Here it is (untested!) in Swift:

```
var login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
login.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if (error != nil){
        //Process error
    }else if result.isCancelled{
        //Handle cancellations
    }else{
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email"){
            //Do work
        }
    }
    })
```

Comment: What do I do if

if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email"){
  //Do work
}

is not getting email

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your permissions to what you want them to be.
Right below your class add:

```
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
```

Comment: Yes, but it's still possible for the user to edit some of these permissions when they go through the FB OAuth. Hence I need to check if the correct permissions were granted